# conditional extracting a column

Tags: text-processing, bioinformatics

I have a Buch of files (3300) which are the result of my genome-scan output `anacovis2_1_summary_betai_reg.out ... anacovis2_3300_summary_betai_reg.out`
and each file look like this (fist few lines):

```
 1    4996     0.03907811     0.19369659   -10.43580084     0.00150707     0.00836902     0.06697258
  1    4997     0.06213154     0.17373333   -10.98540609     0.00213014     0.00556877     0.15361369
  1    4998    -0.00284978     0.19418451    -8.81547738     0.00016505     0.00741737     0.00777931
  1    4999    -0.02047544     0.19574268    -9.12692867    -0.00059062     0.00632552     0.03357265
  1    5000    -0.01769435     0.18560835   -13.15854481    -0.00038595     0.00540918     0.02543350
  2       1     0.04259550     0.20256840   -10.98339784     0.00120126     0.00529516     0.08590396
  2       2    -0.10782050     0.17555969    -9.13783036    -0.00355861     0.00689091     0.21784244
  2       3     0.02548854     0.18571440   -15.42307129     0.00006131     0.00291038     0.00736142
  2       4     0.03084782     0.17813247   -11.99911720     0.00109688     0.00630034     0.06459986
```

the first column is environmental variables ranging from 1 to 26. I want to go through each file and extract only the 4th column for each environmental variable and save them in a file with a suffix of environmental variable number.

I know how to do it separately for each enviornmental variable for example for the variable 1

```
awk '($1==1){print $4>FILENAME"_env1"}'anacovis2_{1..3300}_summary_betai_reg.out
```

or for the variable 2

```
awk '($1==2){print $4>FILENAME"_env2"}'anacovis2_{1..3300}_summary_betai_reg.out
```

but it takes time if I want to do it like this, I wonder whether I can do it faster in a loop for instance.
I tried something like this

```
for i in {1..26};
do awk '($1==i){print $4>FILENAME"_i"}'anacovis2_{1..3300}_summary_betai_reg.out
done
```

but did not work! Can someone help me to sort this out?
thanks

Comment: why not just `awk '{ print $4 >> FILE_$1 }'` ?

Comment: @Shlublu, no it did not work after applying your suggestion

Comment: @Anna1364 Sorry Anna. Removed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is. Do it as this way with `awk` itself only.

```
awk '{print $4>FILENAME"_env"$1}' anacovis2_{1..3300}_summary_betai_reg.out
```

To save each same  *env* from all files into same one file, like env1, env2 and so on just drop the `FILENAME` there and run the command with `{print $4>"env"$1}`.

Comment: yes, it did the job, I wonder what is wrong in my loop. I modified it: for i in {1..3300};
do awk '($1==$i){print $4>FILENAME"_$i"}'anacovis2_{1..3300}_summary_betai_reg.out
done  but did not work

Comment: The problem is that the shell variable `i` is not available within strong quotes (`'`), so it was an unitialized `awk` variable, and getting parsed by `awk` as `$0`.

Comment: @afshin,sorry one thing that I could not understand in your code; _env"$1 what does that mean? I was expecting it will only print out variable1?

Comment: Hi the FILENAME is you know it's Orginal filename for each file awk reads from. and `_env` is a suffix and `$1` will the value of first column. so like `FILENAME_env1`, `FILENAME_env2`, ..., `FILENAME_env26`

Comment: Aha, thanks so much.Is there also anyway to save the outputs for each env in a separete file file while I am running this code: awk '{print $4>FILENAME"_env"$1}' anacovis2_{1..3300}_summary_betai_reg.out?

Comment: Yes, exactly. this is doing what I want, but just wanted to ensure they are being saved based on the order of files? It is important for me to have the from {1..3300}. And I just wanted to ask do you know any good reference that I could improve my bash scripting skills? I have learnt about many basic functions but cannot write codes yet!

Comment: Yes, this will append based on files order that awk reads. and for learning bash I suggest start from [Bash Reference Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/index.html).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/67399/discussion-between-anna1364-and-s).